# php strtotime some day un complete

Tags: php, strtotime

I have some date, like:

```
20 November 06:10
12 November 08:12
10 October 13:23
```

There all in the past 6 months, Now I want to `strtotime()` them, but they are all un complete (lack of year), how to make some process so that I could `strtotime()` them?

Comment: Do you want them for the current year always?

Comment: @sberry, No, may be today become some day in the next year. these days always in the past 6 months relative to `today`

Comment: Those dates won't always be in the past 6 months.  What about June 1, 2013?

Comment: @sberry, if today is `June 1, 2013`, these dates will before `June 1, 2013`, but will not over 6 months(Jan 1, 2013)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dates = array("10 October 13:23", "12 November 08:12", "10 October 13:23");

    foreach($dates as $d){
        $exploded = explode(" ", $d);
        $newDate = array_slice($exploded, 0,2,true)+array(2=>"2012")+array(3 => $exploded[2]);

        //print_r($newDate);
        $time = strtotime(implode($newDate));
        echo $time."<br/>";
    }
```

The output i got is:

```
1349868180
1352704320
1349868180
```

The logic is:

You lack the year, so I exploded the dates into an array to slice them, insert the year (the `+array(2=>"2012")` part) and glue them again with implode, and then run the strtotime.

This work only for this year, so you can use this logic to add the year to all your dates, or in the future there will be absolutely no way to filter dates from different years.

- I added the dates into an array for loop through all of them, you can use the loop other ways, depending on where you have all your dates stored. For example if they are in a database you can include the script in the `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))` part where `$d` would be `$row['date']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.datetime.php) class and its [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [getTimeStamp](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.gettimestamp.php) methods instead of strtotime.

Comment: What did you get so far ? Did you at least try ?

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(date_parse_from_format("d F H:i", '20 November 06:10'));
```

gives you:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 
    [month] => 11
    [day] => 20
    [hour] => 6
    [minute] => 10
    [second] => 0
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)
```